# Correct way to check if Eureka Client has been registered to Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to check if the client has already been registered to Eureka Server.
It successfully registers in the server (I've checked the eureka status page), but cant seem to check its own status.

Currently I have this codes on the client:

```
private static ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager;
private static EurekaClient eurekaClient;

private static synchronized ApplicationInfoManager initializeApplicationInfoManager(EurekaInstanceConfig instanceConfig) {
    if (applicationInfoManager == null) {
        InstanceInfo instanceInfo = new EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider(instanceConfig).get();
        applicationInfoManager = new ApplicationInfoManager(instanceConfig, instanceInfo);
    }

    return applicationInfoManager;
}

private static synchronized EurekaClient initializeEurekaClient(ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager, EurekaClientConfig clientConfig) {
    if (eurekaClient == null) {
        eurekaClient = new DiscoveryClient(applicationInfoManager, clientConfig);
    }

    return eurekaClient;
}
```

And for my checking:

```
ApplicationInfoManager applicationInfoManager = initializeApplicationInfoManager(new MyDataCenterInstanceConfig());
EurekaClient client = initializeEurekaClient(applicationInfoManager, new DefaultEurekaClientConfig());
return client.getInstanceRemoteStatus(); // RETURNS "UNKNOWN"
```

This is the error stacktrace:

```
2019-12-10 11:28:48 [http-nio-8105-exec-1] ERROR c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_UNKNOWN/9ec71a3abda0 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: There is no known eureka server; cluster server list is empty
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:108) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:414) [eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) [eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:265) [eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:257) [eureka-client-1.9.0.jar!/:1.9.0]
    at com.pn.event.controller.HomeController.initializeEurekaClient(HomeController.java:56) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.pn.event.controller.HomeController.index(HomeController.java:65) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Been trying the whole day. Seems like there is not a good document or code sample for this online.

Comment: Can you step back? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: you want to check eureka server health status? Or want to check the health status of registered service?

Comment: @spencergibb I want to have a health check endpoint on my service. say, `/ping` will return if it is currently registered in eureka or not.

Comment: Can you put your application.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like here you are having issue-

```
EurekaClient client = initializeEurekaClient(applicationInfoManager, new DefaultEurekaClientConfig());
return client.getInstanceRemoteStatus(); // RETURNS "UNKNOWN"
```

After initializing the client you are trying to access the status of it. **client.getInstanceRemoteStatus()** returns the last known status of service from eureka registry. In this case last know status is UNKNOWN. Status gets changed when Euraka server cache gets refreshed and shared with service. usually it takes >30 seconds with default configuration.

If you want to check it explicitly you could use endpoint- GET **/eureka/v2/apps/appID/instanceID** , it will return the current status of service from eureka.

You can also check *EurekaClient.java* implementation for better